# How to get the gradient of function from vectors to scalars?

Tags: matlab, gradient

Given a function f:R^600 -> R  `f(x)=0.5*norm(Ax-b)^2`, where `A` is a 400x600 matrix, `b` is 400x1, and both of them are given.

How can I get the `gradient(f)` at some given `x0` in MATLAB?

```
m=400
n=600
A=randn(m,n)
b=randn(m,1)

syms x
f= 0.5*norm(A*x-b)^2
gradient(f,x)
```

However it does not work because it seems it regard `x` as scalar, not a vector.

Answer (score 1):

Given the function:

[image: f(x) = \frac{1}{2}\|Ax-b\|^2]

the gradient is just:

[image: Ax-b]

Check [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus) for further details.

Therefore, your MATLAB implementation is:

```
g = A'*(A*x-b);
```

where g is the gradient of your function for a given x.

Note that A, b and x are numerical, not symbolic.

**Proof**

[image: f(x) = \frac{1}{2}\|Ax-b\|^2]

---

**Symbolic approach**

You can use the following code:

```
N = 3;

A = [1 0 1;
     2 1 -1;
     3 1 0];

b = [1;
     2;
     3];

x = sym('x', [N, 1]);

f = 0.5*norm(A*x-b)^2;

g = sym('g', [N, 1]); % g is the gradient of f
for i=1:N
    g(i) = diff(f,x(i));
end
```

Comment: I do admit that it is a long time ago I have had calculus, but I am quite certain that you lack to take the derivative of the inner function. Making your solution wrong.

Comment: @NickyMattsson. You are right! There is a missing term. I'm going to fix it and I'll add also a reference.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, how can I get the gradient of f by MATLAB instead of the calculation by hand?

Comment: I've added a snippets of code for symbolic calculus.